# AVR C Function returns zero when using operator

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I need to develop a simple thermometer using an AVR ATMEGA88. I'm using a library I found to read the temperature from my thermocouple (type k with max6675). I can read the temperature correctly using the function gettemp(), but when I use an operator on the resulting value it returns 0.

Because the function returns the value in 0.25deg celsius I need to divide by 4, I also need to split the value in two to display on a seven segment display.

My code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "max6675.h"

/*
Max6675 library by Tobias Schlegel, 5.2009
www.tobias-schlegel.de

Report bugs to tobias@drschlegel.de

This software is deliveres as-is and comes with absolute NO warranty.
This software is published under GNU license.
*/

uint16_t gettemp(void);                          //Functie declaratie
void initavr(void);

// Geeft temperatuur per 0.25 graden celsius.
uint16_t gettemp(void) {                          //Haal de temperatuur op
  uint8_t bit = 0, bitnr = 12;                    //Variabelen
  uint8_t foo1 = 0;
  uint16_t Rohdata = 0;
  CS_Port &= ~(1 << CS);                        //Chip select anlegen
  for (foo1 = 0; foo1 < 16; foo1++) {                  //16 Bits Uitlezen
    bit = 15 - foo1;                        //Die Aktuelle Bitnr berechnen.
    SCK_Port |= (1 << SCK);                      //SCK hi
    if ((bit <= 14) && (bit >= 3)) {                  //Einfach mal die 12 relevanten von den 16 Bits ausfiltern
      if ((SO_Pin & (1 << SO))) {                    //WENN SO 1 ist, dann...
        bitnr--;                        //z�hlen wir runter...
        Rohdata |= (1 << bitnr);                // und schieben eine 1 an bit x
      } else {                            //WENN dem NICHT so ist, dann...
        bitnr--;                        //z�hlen wir runter...
        Rohdata &= ~(1 << bitnr);                //und schieben eine 0 an bit x
      }
    } else {                              //weis au nimmer, was das soll.
      bitnr = 12;
    }
    SCK_Port &= ~(1 << SCK);                    //SCK LO
  }
  CS_Port |= (1 << CS);                        //CS HI  //Alles auf Standardkonfig.
  return Rohdata;                            //Geeft de temperatuur terug
}


// getTC() returns 0 if Thermocouple is not connected, 255 if thermocouple is connected
// (to enable this feature T- must be connected to GND)
uint8_t getTC(void) {
  uint8_t TC = 0;
  uint8_t foo1 = 0;

  CS_Port &= ~(1 << CS);                        //Chip select anlegen
  for (foo1 = 0; foo1 < 16; foo1++) {                  //16 Bits einlesen                                               //Die Aktuelle Bitnr berechnen.
    SCK_Port |= (1 << SCK);                      //SCK hi

    if (foo1 == 2) {                          //das 3. bit ist f�r uns relevant.
      if ((SO_Pin & (1 << SO))) {         //Geeft 0 wanneer er geen thermocouple gedeteceerd wordt
        TC = 0;
      } else {                            //Geeft 255 wanneer er een thermocouple gedeteceerd wordt
        TC = 255;
      }
    }
    SCK_Port &= ~(1 << SCK);                    //SCK LO
  }
  CS_Port |= (1 << CS);                        //CS HI
  return TC;                              //Geeft 0 of 255 afhankelijk of thermocouple is gedetecteerd
}

//Initialiseert de MAX6675 en de IO-pins
void init_6675(void) {                          //AVR initialiseren
  SO_DDR &= ~(1 << SO);
  CS_DDR |= (1 << CS);
  SCK_DDR |= (1 << SCK);                        //IOs instellen
  SO_Port |= (1 << SO);                          //Pullups aan. (Belangrijk voor de MAX6675)
  CS_Port |= (1 << CS);                        //CS HI  Poort afkomstig uit de configuratie
  SCK_Port &= ~(1 << SCK);                      //SCK LO
}

void updateTemp(void) {
  const uint16_t numbers[10] = {0b11000000, 0b11111001, 0b10010010, 0b10110000, 0b10101001, 0b10100100, 0b10000100, 0b11110001, 0b10000000, 0b10100000}; //Numbers on 7Segment

  uint16_t temperature =  gettemp() / 4; //Get temperature and divide by 4 to get degrees celcius

  //Split number to display on 7segment
  uint16_t single = temperature % 10;
  uint16_t decimal = (temperature - single) / 10;

//    uint16_t test = 344 / 4; //Test value - this display correctly on 7segment
//    uint16_t single = test % 10;
//    uint16_t decimal = (test - single) / 10;

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    PORTB = 0b00000010;
    PORTD = numbers[single];
    _delay_ms(1);
    PORTB = 0b00000100;
    PORTD = numbers[decimal];
    _delay_ms(1);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  DDRD |= 0b11111111; //Alle D poorten op output
  DDRC |= 0b00011111; //
  DDRB |= 0b11001110; //

  init_6675(); //Initialiseer de MAX6675

  while (1) {

    uint8_t isThereATC =  getTC();

    if (isThereATC == 0) {
      PORTB = 0b01000000; //No Thermocouple
      PORTD = 0b11111111;
    }
    else if (isThereATC == 255) {
      updateTemp();
    }
    else {
      PORTD = 0b11111111; //Error
    }
    _delay_ms(2000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I know my thermocouple works because if I do not use operators and use LED's to display temperature ranges is works correctly.

EDIT:
The problem occurs in the following function. I use `temperature = gettemp() / 4` to get the temperature. this returns 0.

```
 void updateTemp(void) {
      const uint16_t numbers[10] = {0b11000000, 0b11111001, 0b10010010, 0b10110000, 0b10101001, 0b10100100, 0b10000100, 0b11110001, 0b10000000, 0b10100000}; //Numbers on 7Segment

      uint16_t temperature =  gettemp() / 4; //Get temperature and divide by 4 to get degrees celcius

      //Split number to display on 7segment
      uint16_t single = temperature % 10;
      uint16_t decimal = (temperature - single) / 10;

    //    uint16_t test = 344 / 4; //Test value - this display correctly on 7segment
    //    uint16_t single = test % 10;
    //    uint16_t decimal = (test - single) / 10;

      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ //Display on 7Segment
        PORTB = 0b00000010;
        PORTD = numbers[single]; //Number right
        _delay_ms(1);
        PORTB = 0b00000100;
        PORTD = numbers[decimal]; //Number left
        _delay_ms(1);
      }
    }
```

EDIT2 :
I removed the divide by 4 and used the following code to determine the value of `temperature`

```
       if (temperature == 0){
            PORTB = 0b10000000; //Green LED
            PORTD = 0b11111111;
          }
else if (temperature > 0 && temperature < 100) {
PORTB = 0b00000100; //Blue LED
            PORTD = 0b11111111;
}
          else {
            PORTB = 0b00001000; //Red LED
            PORTD = 0b11111111;
          }
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Where exactly in this code is the problem? Don't jut dump your entire program here asking others to debug it for you. Post only the relevant piece of information, or point out exactly what should be reviewed. The `temperature` variable in `temperature =  gettemp() / 4` will be set to zero if and only if the function `gettemp()` returns 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @barakmanos I'm sorry, in previous treats I was asked to share all code. The problem occurs when I try to get the temperature (inside the updateTemp function). When i use `temperature = gettemp();` everything seems to be working, but when i divide this by 4, `temperature = gettemp() /4` i returns 0.

Comment: Well, debug your code and check what value is returned by `gettemp()`. If it's between 0 and 3, then the result of dividing it by 4 is obviously 0.

Comment: The gettemp() normally returns between 80 and 90, so divided by 4 it should definitely not be 0. As this code is for an avr, I cannot get the actual value because I have no screen.

Comment: You have a debugger, don't you?

Comment: unfortunately no. This is part of a school project, we get all the components but no debugging hardware.

Comment: take out the divide by 4 and see what happens, it will be too large but will give you  aclue about the value being returned by gettemp

Comment: @pm100, I already took out the divide by 4. as i cannot display this on the 7segment (because i would need other operators) I used several LED's to get the value. `      if (temperature == 0){
        PORTB = 0b10000000; //green LED
        PORTD = 0b11111111;
      }
      else {
        PORTB = 0b00001000; //Red LED
        PORTD = 0b11111111;
      }`

Comment: so you have no debug output other than the 7 segments?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I got some leds, 7segment and a few other components. but no seperate debugger. I use a USBasp to program the AVR, but I don't know if I can use that to debug.

Comment: use the 14 segments to display the 14  least significant bits of the gettemp return value. Hard work but you gotta do it

Comment: Good idea, will definitely try doing that.

Comment: @StefSpakman Unforutantly the USBasp cannot be used to debug, you will need a JTAG for that purpose.